# Core Bluetooth characteristic not updating value

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios7, core-bluetooth

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` isn't being called as expected. I need to send a rather long string, so I'm cutting it up into 5-character chunks and "updating" those at 0.03s intervals. Here's the code:

[The view controller code.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zyiv7ssa36vogh/BluetoothViewController.m)

It conforms to the necessary protocols, and everything works fine, except for the fact that `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` only gets called once for the list name and once for the "START" chunk.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the NSTTimer to not repeat:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self
  selector:@selector(sendList) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

This way it runs once and stops. Change `repeats` to `YES` and the sends will actually start to happen. Use more logging to figure such issues out. :)

Note there are some other issues with your code too:

1. you shouldn't sleep on the main thread. The managers are currently initialized to use the main queue.
2. You shouldn't release the peripheral as long as it is connected or is connecting (issue in `viewwillDisappear:`)
3. The list handling is really "mysterious". Objective-C is a beautiful, really expressive language, use it to your own advantage. (I'm missing the named parameters so much in Java)

If you run into more issues, go ahead and ask them in separate questions.

Comment: Amazing. The "timer" way of doing it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Macro206 I'm happy this helped! Keep on doing `core-bluetooth` it's the way of the future :)

Comment: You just wanted to read data? you have not written any data? i am having some what similar issue i am writting message using write method and want to read same data using read method but i am not getting messgae in this method.Could not find any solution.